# Python - psutil.sensors_battery() returns None in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, psutil

I have a Python script that runs in the background and checks various battery information with psutil in Python. The script worked perfectly back when I was using Windows, but after I switched to Ubuntu, I have problems with it. Whenever I run the command: psutil.sensors_battery() it returns None, regardless if the charger is plugged in or not. I have a HP computer. Has anyone had similar difficulties with psutil.sensors_battery() on Linux?